# edit existing inline style using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some html which seems to default to :

```
<ul style="top: 72px; visibility: hidden;">
```

But i need Jquery to rescue me and change top: 72px to top: 37px

Is this possible? as in Firefox 37px seems to show up but in IE7 it shows up as 72px

Thanks

**edit: added more info**

the ul id = treemenu1

and its parent element is div class = treemenu

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$('#treemenu1').css({ top: 37 });
```

Should work fine.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NdW4t/) of POC.

Comment: added more info to original post

Comment: Ok, all that does is change the selector

Comment: its the last li in my UL and the a tag is as follows: <a href="#" class="mainfoldericon">DISTRIBUTOR RESOURCES</a>

Comment: Wait, what? I thought the question was how to chang ethe `top` value in the ul?

Comment: yeah it is.. the UL is created within the LI to create teh sub options. IE doesnt like the javascript for the menu and is adding 72px top to the UL.. so i need to check its a certain UL based on the content of the A tag.

Comment: Ok, well regardless of where it is this will work for the `ul` with an id of `treemenu1` anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 12):

I would select your ul by id:

```
$("#treemenu1").css("top", "37px");
```

Also note that you can update multiple css properties at once by passing an object in, whose keys and values correspond to css properties, and their new values:

```
$("#treemenu1").css({ "top": "37px", "bottom": "20px" });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$("ul").css("top", "37px");//this should work in all browsers.
```

Comment: its the last li in my UL and the a tag is as follows: <a href="#" class="mainfoldericon">DISTRIBUTOR RESOURCES</a>