# How to edit the style attribute from an element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to edit the style attribute with jQuery.
Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a div

```
<div style="background:url('images/image.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;color:red;">
hello
</div>
```

and I need to change the `background` to something else like `image2.png`

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [**jQuery documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/) (that's the first place to start looking)? Especially the [`.css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [edit existing inline style using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359224/edit-existing-inline-style-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('div').css('background', 'url(images/image2.png)')
```

To set your entire background string, you can use a property map:

```
var cssObj = {
  'background-image': 'url(images/image2.png)',
  'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
  'background-attachment': 'scroll',
  'background-position': '0 0',
  'background-color': 'transparent'
}
$('div').css(cssObj);
```

Comment: He has a string there, for his background properties. Could you show him the difference between .css() and .css({});?

Comment: Thank you, and if you tell me also how to remove it it will be helpfull, or else i will make another question about that, without touching the color?

Comment: @themhz: `color` is a different property and will not be affected by setting the `background` property. I suggest to have a look at the documentation for more information/examples.

Comment: Added in using `.css({})`. As @FelixKling said, this will not affect the `color` property at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   var cssObj = {
      'background-image' : 'url(http://www.mousescrappers.com/forums/xperience/icons/teacups24.png)',
      'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',      
    }
   $("div").css(cssObj);
});
```

The above script loads image on the document ready. Note that it loads for all Div's. So you better be more specific about the element ( use Id or class as selector)

Example http://jsfiddle.net/XsRuC/9/